# Minimum fields to Maximize Payment Conversions?

Tags: api, bluesnap

I took a look at Bluesnap's Auth Capture API - https://developers.bluesnap.com/v8976-XML/docs/auth-capture specifically the "card-holder-info" element.

What minimum fields needs to be passed to maximize payment conversions? I want to map these fields to my checkout UI page where I would like to have my customers enter minimum number of fields to strike a balance between being frictionless vs maximize conversions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimal details of the card holder are **first name**, **last name** and **zip code**. That's all the information BlueSnap requires to process the purchase.

The process is already pretty streamlined. From the optional fields you may add, adding *country* and *state* might have some effect as some processors use this information to validate the shopper.